# Windows server создание демона как на Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, сервер, flask

Вопрос может быть очень странный, но мне нужно создать на виндовом компе процесс демон как на Linux. В Linux так же есть утилитка supervisor. Для винды аналога не нашёл, может кто то сталкивался и поможет)

Нужно для того, что бы развернуть Flask.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55725881/12785139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нужно оформить код пакетом, если он из нескольких файлов, и уложить в site-packages.

```
myflask\
  __init__.py
  myapp.py
  service.py
```

Установи [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases). Рекомендую версию 225 (*на конец 2020*).

```
py -m pip install pywin32-225-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

Добавить в PATH папки pywin32 (если устанавливать из экзешника - должен сам прописаться):

> этот компьютер — свойства — дополнительные параметры системы — дополнительно — переменные среды.

```
Путь к питон\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32
Путь к питон\Lib\site-packages\win32
```

В `myapp.py` реализуй `app`. В service:

```
def start():
    from myapp import app
    app.run()


WINSERVICE = False

try:
    if os.name == 'nt':
        import win32serviceutil
        import win32service
        import servicemanager
        WINSERVICE = True
except:
    pass

if WINSERVICE:
    class AppServerSvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
        _svc_name_ = "MyService"
        _svc_display_name_ = "MyService"

        def __init__(self, args):
            import multiprocessing as mp
            win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
            self.proc = mp.Process(target=start)

        def SvcStop(self):
            self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
            self.proc.terminate()

        def SvcDoRun(self):
            servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                                  servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                                  (self._svc_name_, ''))
            try:
                self.proc.start()
                self.proc.join()
            except Exception as e:
                import traceback
                import sys
                exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
                servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                                  0xF000,
                                  (self._svc_name_, "\n".join(traceback.format_tb(exc_traceback))))

def entry_point():
    if WINSERVICE:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
    else:
        start()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    entry_point()
```

Теперь выполнить для установки службы:

```
py -m myflask.service install
```

Сервис появится в службах Windows. И для старта

```
py -m myflask.service start
```