# Как создать службу Windows для Python-приложения, собранного через pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Всем привет!
Написал приложение на Python, собрал из него exe-файл через pyinstaller.
Как мне можно создать рабочую службу Windows для этого файла?

Пытался через:

> sc.exe create ИМЯ_СЛУЖБЫ binpath="ПУТЬ_К_ФАЙЛУ"

Служба создалась, но при её запуске получаю: "Ошибка 1053. Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно".

Comment: Большая часть ответа на вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1245857/windows-server-создание-демона-как-на-linux/1245989#1245989 , решит проблему с ошибкой 1053.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Windows server создание демона как на Linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1245857/windows-server-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-linux)